# How to write a SQL Server query to generate two output table base on two tables using the condition below

Tags: sql, join, between

I'm trying to write a T-SQL query that joins two table and creates two output queries base on the following condition.

join table F1 to table F2 by ITEM_NO.

OUTPUT1 should only contain the records where the ITEM_NO matches and the MVT_DATE date falls between the SDATE and EDATE.

OUTPUT2 should only contain the records where ITEM_NO matches and the MVT_DATE does not fall between the SDATE and EDATE.

For example, item 67890 below has three matching records in F2 but only one record falls between SDATE & EDATE. The other two records are discarded because we found at least 1 matching record that fall between the dates. If no records fall between SDATE and EDATE then the information from record F1 would go to OUTPUT2.

[image]

Comment: And what have you tried?  In my opinion, the question as written is too broad because you have two distinct questions.

Comment: 1st Query - OUTPUT 1

SELECT * FROM F1
INNER JOIN F2 
ON (F1.ITEM_NO = F2.ITEM_NO) AND (MVT_DATE BETWEEN SDATE AND EDATE)

2nd Query - OUTPUT 2

SELECT * FROM F2
INNER JOIN F2
ON (F1.ITEM_NO = F2.ITEM_NO) AND NOT (MVT_DATE BETWEEN SDATE AND EDATE)

ON 2nd query I'm getting multilple records from F1 because the conditon is true for each record in F2 for ITEM_NO = 12345